# How to change theme in JupyterLab Desktop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've installed the JupyterLab Desktop application found here:

[jupyterlab-desktop](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop)

and wanted to change the theme noticing only two options Jupyter Dark and Light. So naturally with the extensions setting I've tried to install a theme such as monokai as such,

```
jupyter labextension install @hokyjack/jupyterlab-monokai-plus
```

Then I get the following warning

```
(Deprecated) Installing extensions with the jupyter labextension install 
command is now deprecated and will be removed in a 
future major version of JupyterLab.

Users should manage prebuilt extensions with package managers like 
pip and conda, and extension authors are encouraged to distribute 
their extensions as prebuilt packages
```

So is there no way to change the theme in JupyterLab Desktop other then the default?

Comment: As it says, that isn't the way to install themes in any current JupyterLab now. You need to research the new ways. [This](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/issues/579#issuecomment-1431567536) and [this](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/issues/399#issuecomment-1041902634) might help for JupyterLab Desktop. I also note there is a dialog covered under 'Theme support' here which is more recent and it is referenced in [the former link](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/issues/579#issuecomment-1431567536), I provided.

Comment: Also see [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/issues/582#issuecomment-1434066148), that example has the `pip install` covered earlier in the thread, which is reiterated [here](https://github.com/dracula/jupyterlab#install). JupyterLab is evolved quite a lot in the last several years. The extensions are a lot of easier than the classic Notebook interface. This is in part why version seven of what is the document-centric version (presently classsic) [will be built off JupyterLab components](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html)

Comment: The pip install JDracula worked, so now I working on finding other themes I can install this way. I guess it pretty much works the same way to install JupyterLab themes. Also I have went on my setting and unchecked sync jupyterlab theme

Comment: Look for the ones that have recent updates [here at the Python Package Index(PyPI)](https://pypi.org/search/?q=jupyterlab+theme) and that mention JupyterLab 3 or greater in the description. That usually helps you sort. However, it isn't fool-proof. Some have the `pip install` working as the banner across the top shows,  but didn't bother updating the documentation.

Comment: Yes I've noticed not all of these have changed. The ones who support the pip install works at least and I can find a few to use. Thank you for the help

Comment: I've noticed with nodeJS, you can install those with labextension however this will be temporary until its fully removed in a major Jupyter update